# Update int array based on parent

Tags: arrays, postgresql, sql-update

I have the following int[] in my database:

```
'{0}'
'{0,0}'
'{0,0,0}'
'{0,0,0,0}'
```

This column is used to sort my tree data. Now when a parent updates it's order the children should also update. For example if the second record updates it's order to 1 it should result in the following.

```
'{0}'
'{0,1}'
'{0,1,0}'
'{0,1,0,0}'
```

So I was wondering what the query would be to update record 3 and 4. In case it's not clear what I am asking leave a comment I can add additional information.

**Screenshot of my actual data:**

[image: Screenshot of my actual data]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
update t
set sort[2] = 1
where sort[1:2] = array[0,0]
```